# Usage of "to" multiple times in a sentence

Tags: grammar

In the sentence, "Are u able `to` login `to` XYZ System."

I word `to` has been used multiple times. Is it correct usage?

Comment: Why do I see down vote? I am not from English country! Can't I ask basic questions?

Comment: The tooltip on the downvote button gives the principal reasons. We do already have a [very similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425270/repeated-prepositions-e-g-of). You may also be interested in [ell.se].

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's okay. There's nothing wrong with repeating prepositions.

Comment: **Why** is there nothing wrong with it?